# timestamp date today

Tags: sql, date, timestamp

Hi guys could you please help me with this. I know it is silly but can't find unswer anywhere:

I have a query that shows events from the today time_stamp but I want to include today as well. How do I add this to this query?

```
 ...
WHERE events.event_date > current_timestamp
ORDER BY convert (event_date, date) ASC
```

As it is formed it doesn't show the event of the day.
Hope I made it clear.
Please help me many thanks. F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for anybody who might have the same problem I sorlved it as follow:

```
 WHERE events.event_date > current_timestamp 
 OR TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, events.event_date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = 0 
 ORDER BY convert (event_date, date) ASC ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
declare @t table(eventdt datetime)
insert into @t 
    select '12/12/2009' union all 
    select '12/15/2009'union all 
    select '11/27/2009'union all -- today's date
    select '11/26/2009' union all
    select '10/26/2009'
select * from @t where eventdt > =  CONVERT(varchar(10),current_timestamp,101)
```

**Output:**

```
eventdt
2009-12-12 00:00:00.000
2009-12-15 00:00:00.000
2009-11-27 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Sorry pewed it doesn't work on my. My query is as follow:

SELECT event_ID, DATE_FORMAT(events.event_date, '%W, %D %M %Y') AS event_date
FROM events
WHERE events.event_date >= current_timestamp
ORDER BY convert (event_date, date) ASC

Comment: Just confirm me if CONVERT(varchar(10),current_timestamp,101) works in mysql or not. I am a sql server guy. I thought the same will work for mysql too!

Comment: See , I searched in the net to find a similar function as CONVERT(varchar(10),current_timestamp,101) and I got CONVERT(current_timestamp, CHAR(8)) from http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,51791,51793#msg-51793.

The program I have given is 100% working in Sql Server but may need to modify only CONVERT(varchar(10),current_timestamp,101) in my sql.

Try my program first after making that portion compatible to mysql and then implement that in your program. 

I am confident that you can do it and will get success

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly current_timestamp is a datetime containing hh:mm:ss.

To get the date only use

```
DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0current_timestamp))
```

Which should get youjust the *Day Month Year* value.

Then you can change your code to

```
WHERE events.event_date >= DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0current_timestamp))
ORDER BY convert (event_date, date) ASC
```

Comment: Hi astander. it is a yyyy/mm/dd date. What I need is simply to show the today event as well. As it is formed my query does not show the today event because is already passed.

Comment: What DB are you using? Sql Server?

Comment: OK, can yuo extract the date part from the current_timestamp? is so, use that date and change the > to >=

Comment: It does show this way but it keeps showing for all events more then one days old.. That's I need to show the today event but until 24.00 hours. So i don't want to show the today event tomorrow.
Not sure I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Hi Astander, do you know what will be the compatible for CONVERT(varchar(10),current_timestamp,101) in MySql. Will it be CONVERT(@StartDate, CHAR(10)) ?

I don't know ... if you know please help the OP

Comment: I searched in the net but only came up with CONVERT(@StartDate, CHAR(10)). Also I have no experience in MySql. If you have so or if you know pls help him. Sorry if I made any mistake by asking u in this way. My intension is to help the OP. Because I guess he is struggling a lot (: